# Previous travel evidence required

Tags: visas, uk, standard-visitor-visas

I am stuck in progressing the visitor visa profile of my parents as it is not letting me go to next step. My parents have never travelled overseas yet and they have no history of travel. The online application is not progressing further because it says I have to attach required documents for this " Evidence of Applicant's travel history."

I am not sure what I should attach.

Comment: From where to where do they want to travel?
What site are you using?

Answer (score 1):

The question is asking for travel history in the past 10 years. If the person you are applying for has no travel history, select no *no travel history*.

If they do provide evidence as shown in your passport. Note: Building up travel history will help your UK visa application.

This is one of the documents you need to provide as mentioned on the [GOV website](https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa/documents-you-must-provide):

> You might also need:
>
> - details of your travel history for the past 10 years (as shown in your passport)